# Refreshing a pivot table with a cell value

Tags: vba, date, pivot

I have the following code,

```
'latest date effort
Dim DataDataData As Long
DataDataData = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A1048576"))
Dim DataDataData2 As String
DataDataData2 = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataDataData)        

'refresh pivot#1
Sheets("Data").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date").AutoSort xlAscending _
    , "Date"

'refresh pivot#2
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = _
    Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataDataData)
```

The refresh pivot #1, works OK and does what I want it to, however, the second one errors with Application-defined or object-defined error.

I want it to refresh the pivot with the latest cell of my data list, which would be the latest date of the data list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date to a string:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = _
    cstr(Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataDataData))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working :( getting the same error message.

Comment: what gives: cstr(Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataDataData)) as a result?

Comment: Row 65, which is the value I want to filter by, which is todays date

Comment: Record a macro, filter your pivot on todays date and look if there are any differences with the code above. I really think there will be a difference in the format of the date.